# Spring boot v2 No qualifying bean of type TestRestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-test, spring-mvc-test

I am getting an error when trying to get the TestRestTemplate. Is there any way to get the TestRestTemplate or test the ErrorController?

error log: https://pastebin.com/XVPU9qrb

[Main test class:](https://github.com/dungsil/ppalli/blob/c3c2c6da6da80d12e8fea22c0f629bf69ea69fac/apps/api/src/test/kotlin/io/kuark/ppalli/PpalliApiTest.kt)

```kotlin
package io.kuark.ppalli

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = [PpalliApi::class], webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class PpalliApiTest {

  @Test
  fun contextLoads() {}
}
```

[Unit test class:](https://github.com/dungsil/ppalli/blob/c3c2c6da6da80d12e8fea22c0f629bf69ea69fac/apps/api/src/test/kotlin/io/kuark/ppalli/infrastructure/error/FallbackErrorControllerTest.kt)

```kotlin
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

@WebMvcTest
class FallbackErrorControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  lateinit var http: TestRestTemplate

  @Test
  fun handleError() {
    val result = http.getForObject("/error", String::class.java);

    assertEquals("""{"code": "NOT_FOUND"}""", result)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `@WebMvcTest`, Spring Boot won't start the embedded Tomcat server and you won't be able to access your endpoints over a port. Instead, Spring Boot [configures a mocked servlet environment that you directly interact with using `MockMvc`](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/):

```
@WebMvcTest
class FallbackErrorControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

  @Test
  fun handleError() {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/error")).andExpect(status().isOk);
  }
}
```

MockMvc even comes with its own [Kotlin DSL](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/mockmvc-kotlin-dsl).

When using `@SpringBootTest` and `webEnvironment=RANDOM_PORT` however, Spring Boot will auto-configure Tomcat and expose your application on a random port. This will be a real servlet environment where you can use `TestRestTemplate` as an HTTP client to interact and test your endpoints.